# How to stream a DataSet using remoting

Tags: c#, sql, remoting

I got an assignment for an existing application where the clients communicate with a server using remoting. The clients do some statistics and for them they ask the server for big DataSet objects. These DataSets can hold more than 100.000 records and thus the server gets a lot of pressure memory-wise as it reads the information from the database for sending back the DataSets.

And now to my question: would it be possible to "stream" the DataSet back to the client so that the server never holds more than - for example - 2.000 records at any time? I know that I could do some paging, but as I understand it, the Fill method from the DataSet always reads the whole content. Even when you use the Fill( DataSet dataSet, int startRecord, int maxRecords, string srcTable) it just seems to read everything and then return the specified maxRecords.

The next issue is that we would call the Fill method TotalSize/maxRecords times and so we would query the database server many times with the same query (and the different pages).

I am thinking about something like a DataReader were I just query the database once and then I iterate over all records "streaming" back the "pages".  I just don't know how to stream the information back and then continue reading the information.

Would it be possible?

Comment: What would be the problem using a DataReader?

Comment: @Magnus that could make for a very chatty interface, if it even works (I haven't tested it)

Comment: @Magnus: Well, this could be part of the solution. I could read using a DataReader and every x records send them back to the client. The question as I said would be how to send the information back to the client and continue reading with the DataReader. If I just return the information, the caller would need to call me again asking for the next "page" and then I will query the database again. I imagine something like streaming a video or a file download... you get the different parts continuously.

Comment: Maybe include a callback to the client that can be used to send the data back.